# How to show succes alert on file upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, model-view-controller, upload

I'm currently working on a project where I upload files with the following code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ImportOther", "Mapper", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                   <p>
                       <label class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                           Other JSON / XML <input type="file" name="jsonFileOther" onchange="this.form.submit()" style="display: none;">
                       </label>
                   </p>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I show a succes alert when file has been uploaded? I've used alerts in javascript so far. Hope anyone has some suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Submitting a form containing a `File` input is just like submitting any other form. It posts to the web server and the web server returns a response, typically a page. You'd show the confirmation message there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have submitted your form to the `Controller`, based upon your upload result, you can set a message using `ViewBag`.

In your `Controller`:

```
if(fileUpload == true)
{
ViewBag.UploadMessage = "File Successfully Uploaded";
}
else
{
ViewBag.UploadMessage = "Could Not Upload File";
}
```

You can use the `ViewBag` like this in your `View`:

```
@if(ViewBag.UploadMessage != null)
{
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

alert('@ViewBag.UploadMessage ');

});

</script>

}
```

Note: Instead of using `return RedirectToAction()`, use `return View()` to preserve your `ViewBag` variable.

Comment: Where I put the if statement in my view?

Comment: And I'm returning my View like this: "return View("~/Views/Mapper/Index.cshtml");"

Comment: In your `head` section of the `View` or the `scripts` section if you have created one.

Comment: @NielsStenden If your `View` is in the same `Controller` then you can simply return `return View("Index");`